# how to put windows node into K8S cluster?

Tags: windows, kubernetes

I want to operate a Windows container. So I have made a Windows by Docker. And I have built a K8S cluster by binary way. However, although I install calico, the Windows node show NotReady. Why did I fail? How to debug? My version is 1.23.5.

Possible Problem:
When I operate kubelet.exe, there is an error:
E0809 21:35:03.130991   13208 server.go:225] "Failed to validate kubelet configuration" err="[invalid configuration: CgroupsPerQOS (--cgroups-per-qos) true is not supported on Windows, invalid configuration: EnforceNodeAllocatable (--enforce-node-allocatable) [pods] is not supported on Windows]" path="&TypeMeta{Kind:,APIVersion:,}"

Answer (score 0):

The error message on your description indicates there's something wrong with the config file on your Windows node, regarding `cgroup`. Did you follow the official documentation to deploy the Windows node? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/windows/intro/